# Issue on simple WP_Query with posts meta data

Tags: wordpress

I have a custom post type 'event' and a meta field 'event_repeat'. I want to show only those events that have the 'weekly' value in 'event_repeat'.

My code for the query:

```
<?php   
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'meta_query' => array (
            'key' => 'event_repeat',
            'value' => 'weekly',
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    );

    $events_future_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>
```

But the loop shows ALL events regardless the settings in 'meta_query'. I will be very thankful for you help.

Comment: Are you using `$post_array` or `$events_future_query` in your loop? Something like this `while($events_future_query->have_posts()): $events_future_query->the_post(); endwhile();`. Notice that you call `get_posts()` before you have defined the `$args` so if that is what you are trying to loop over you should move the definition of `$args` before the call to `get_posts()`

Comment: I think `$post_array` can be removed, it seems to do nothing here. I have removed it. Now there is only `$events_future_query` and I use it for my loop. But this didn't solve the problem(